# Multibyte Characters corrupt to ???? when read from database and posted to ASP Page using HTTPURLConnection

Tags: java, oracle, asp-classic, multibyte, corrupt-data

In my java code,I am retrieving some multibyte data from database and making some xml DOM, with that data as the value of some node then converting the DOM to String and posting bytest to ASP Page via HTTPURLConnection , but somehow at receiver end the data is appearing as ???? instead of some multibyte values.Please suggest what to do.

Things that i am already doing..

1) I have set `-Dfile.encoding =UTF8` as System Property
2)While using `TransformerFactory` for converting my XML DOM to String , i have set

```
 transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8")
```

to make sure that the  encoding is proper there.
Please suggest where i am getting wrong.

@Jon Skeet Few more things to add here... 1) I am getting data from database correctly 2) Transformed XML also appears to be proper, as i checked by saving it to my local file system.
For posting earlier i was using something like

```
'dout = new DataOutputStream(urlconn.getOutputStream());'  
 'dout.write(strXML.getBytes());' 
 'dout.write(strXML);'
```

and the resulting data at the receiver end was getting converted to ????? but then i switched to
'

```
dout=new OutputStreamWriter(urlconn.getOutputStream(),"UTF8");' 
'dout.write(strXML);'
```

then data at receiver end appears to be proper ... but the problem occurs with the way it is handled at receiver end in this case. in my receiver ASP code i am using `objStream.WriteLine (oXMLDom.xml)`
 ... and here it fails and starts to give internal server error... please suggest whats wrong with second approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *lots* of potential conversions going on there. You should verify the data at every step:

- Check that you're getting it out of the database correctly
- See what the transformed XML looks like
- Watch what goes over the network (including HTTP headers)
- Check exactly what you're getting in ASP

Don't just print out the strings *as* strings - log the Unicode value of each character, by casting it to `int`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
{
    char c = text.charAt(i);
    log("Character " + c + " - " + (int) c);
}
```

Comment: @schhajed: I don't know what you mean. This is just suggesting things you should be looking at. When you've found where the information is being corrupted, you can fix it at that point. But you need to isolate where it's failing first.

Comment: @Jon Skeet please have a look at my edited question , i think i have figured out the exact point where its getting corrupted.. please help.

Comment: @schhajed: Right. Using `DataOutputStream` was definitely wrong, and `OutputStreamWriter` is a much better idea. Now, when you say "ASP" - is this VB6 ASP classic code? And how are you performing the post operation?

Comment: @Jon Skeet yes its VB6 ASP classic code. and i am using `HttpUrlConnection` to post the XML that is in string format.. as  `dout.write(strXML);` .. also at receiver ASP when i save it to some path using ` oXMLDom.save(filePath)` then its getting saved properly but when using `objStream.WriteLine (oXMLDom.xml)` it starts to give 500 Internal server error..pls suggest

Comment: @schhajed: What exactly is giving the internal error? The ASP server? You're giving several lines of code, but not making it clear where they're executing. It would really help if you'd put this code into the question, with each bit of code in the context of where it's running.

Comment: @Jon Skeet sorry to create confusion.Through a java code i am posting some XML to an classic ASP page, there it gets stored to a filer via `objStream.WriteLine (oXMLDom.xml)` , in case i am using `OutputStreamWriter` the data at receiver is not corrupted but it gives internal server error while i write to filer via `objStream.WriteLine (oXMLDom.xml)`, for testing purposes when i am saving it to a path using `oXMLDom.save(filePath)` there the XML file is not corrupted..i hope i am clear now ..please let me know if you want to know anything else from my side.and Yes the ASP Server is giving Err

Comment: @schhajed: As I say, please edit this code into the question. It sounds like the error is now just to do with writing to the filer and has nothing to do with the Java side any more. Does the ASP server not have any logs which can give you information about what's going wrong?